# Loop throu objects in object with dotted name and filter for attribute Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, filter

I have a global variable ("ccu-192_168_30_22") with the content:

```
{
    "values": {
        "VirtualDevices.INT0000001:1.CONTROL_MODE": {
            "topic": "",
            "payload": 0,
            "deviceName": "F2-1315.03"
            "datapoint": "CONTROL_MODE",
            "room": "F2"
        },
        "HmIP-RF.00201BE9A13271:1.CONTROL_MODE": {
            "topic": "",
            "payload": 0,
            "deviceName": "F02A-1315.02"
            "datapoint": "CONTROL_MODE",
            "room": "F02A"
        },
        "HmIP-RF.00265BE98E8C53:0.UNREACH": {
            "topic": "",
            "payload": 0,
            "deviceName": "F1-1315.01"
            "datapoint": "UNREACH",
            "room": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get a list with the deviceName and room, but only from the objects with "datapoint": "CONTROL_MODE". Here is my example Code.

```
for (var device in global.get("ccu-192_168_30_22").values) {
if (device.datapoint == "CONTROL_MODE") {
    list.push(device.deviceName);
    list.push(device.room);
    }
}
msg.payload = list;
return msg;
```

But I only get msg.payload: array[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A filter and a map will do it

I had to add some commas to your object

```js
const data = {
    "values": {
        "VirtualDevices.INT0000001:1.CONTROL_MODE": {
            "topic": "",
            "payload": 0,
            "deviceName": "F2-1315.03",
            "datapoint": "CONTROL_MODE",
            "room": "F2"
        },
        "HmIP-RF.00201BE9A13271:1.CONTROL_MODE": {
            "topic": "",
            "payload": 0,
            "deviceName": "F02A-1315.02",
            "datapoint": "CONTROL_MODE",
            "room": "F02A"
        },
        "HmIP-RF.00265BE98E8C53:0.UNREACH": {
            "topic": "",
            "payload": 0,
            "deviceName": "F1-1315.01",
            "datapoint": "UNREACH",
            "room": ""
        }
    }
}
const obj = Object.values(data.values)
  .filter(({datapoint}) => datapoint === "CONTROL_MODE")
  .map(({deviceName,room}) => ({deviceName,room}))
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will narrow it down to such form as:

```
{
   "VirtualDevices.INT0000001:1.CONTROL_MODE":{
      "topic":"",
      "payload":0,
      "deviceName":"F2-1315.03",
      "datapoint":"CONTROL_MODE",
      "room":"F2"
   },
   "HmIP-RF.00201BE9A13271:1.CONTROL_MODE":{
      "topic":"",
      "payload":0,
      "deviceName":"F02A-1315.02",
      "datapoint":"CONTROL_MODE",
      "room":"F02A"
   },
   "HmIP-RF.00265BE98E8C53:0.UNREACH":{
      "topic":"",
      "payload":0,
      "deviceName":"F1-1315.01",
      "datapoint":"UNREACH",
      "room":""
   }
}
```

You can just do this:

```
Object.values(your_data).filter(item => item.datapoint === "CONTROL_MODE");
```

Comment: That is not enough